# Mouseup and mousedown event is not working in br tag

Tags: html

As requested, I need to add mouse up and mouse down event for break tag in html, here is the sample of my br tag, but it's not working, is there anything incorrect? Thanks.

```
<br onmouseup="top.onMouseUpEssence('3');"onmousedown="top.onMouseDownEssence('3');">
```

Comment: Does a break tag even have size?

Comment: What are you trying to click on? `<br>` tags don't render anything visible.

Comment: Even if I style it with block display and dimensions it doesn't show. The question is nonsensical.

Comment: you should pick paragraph that is near your br tag...

Comment: “*As requested*”? By whom? With what end result in mind?

Answer (score -1):

Br tag is an empty tag. If the space between br and / is omitted it won't be understood by the browser. It is just a simple tag used to create line breaks. Your question is not valid according to me.